# color depth reduction with opencv and LUT

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, depth

I'd like to perform a color reduction via color depth scaling.

Like this example:
[image]

the first image is CGA resolution, the second is EGA, the third is HAM.
I'd like to do it with cv::LUT because i think it is the betterway to do it.
I can do with greyscale with this code:

```
Mat img = imread("test1.jpg", 0);
uchar* p;
Mat lookUpTable(1, 256, CV_8U);
p = lookUpTable.data;
for( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    p[i] = 16 * (i/16)
LUT(img, lookUpTable, reduced);
```

original:[image]

color reduced: [image]

but if i try to do it with color I get strange result..

[image]

with this code:

```
imgColor = imread("test1.jpg");
Mat reducedColor;
int n = 16;
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    uchar value = floor(i/n) * n;
    cout << (int)value << endl;
    lut.at<Vec3b>(i)[2]= (value >> 16) & 0xff;
    lut.at<Vec3b>(i)[1]= (value >> 8) & 0xff;
    lut.at<Vec3b>(i)[0]= value & 0xff;
} 
LUT(imgColor, lut, reducedColor);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have moved on by now, but the root of the problem is that you are doing a 16-bit shift to `uchar value`, which is just 8-bits long. Even an 8-bit shift in this case is too much, as you'll erase all the bits in the `uchar`. Then there is the fact that the [`cv::LUT` documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut) explicitly states that `src` must be an "input array of 8-bit elements", which clearly isn't the case in your code. The net result is that only the first channel of the color image (the Blue channel) is transformed by `cv::LUT`.

The best way to work around these limitations is to split color images across channels, transform each channel separately, and then merge the transformed channels into a new color image. See the code below:

```
/*
Calculates a table of 256 assignments with the given number of distinct values.

Values are taken at equal intervals from the ranges [0, 128) and [128, 256),
such that both 0 and 255 are always included in the range.
*/
cv::Mat lookupTable(int levels) {
    int factor = 256 / levels;
    cv::Mat table(1, 256, CV_8U);
    uchar *p = table.data;

    for(int i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
        p[i] = factor * (i / factor);
    }

    for(int i = 128; i < 256; ++i) {
        p[i] = factor * (1 + (i / factor)) - 1;
    }

    return table;
}

/*
Truncates channel levels in the given image to the given number of
equally-spaced values.

Arguments:

image
    Input multi-channel image. The specific color space is not
    important, as long as all channels are encoded from 0 to 255.

levels
    The number of distinct values for the channels of the output
    image. Output values are drawn from the range [0, 255] from
    the extremes inwards, resulting in a nearly equally-spaced scale
    where the smallest and largest values are always 0 and 255.

Returns:

Multi-channel images with values truncated to the specified number of
distinct levels.
*/
cv::Mat colorReduce(const cv::Mat &image, int levels) {
    cv::Mat table = lookupTable(levels);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> c;
    cv::split(image, c);
    for (std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator i = c.begin(), n = c.end(); i != n; ++i) {
        cv::Mat &channel = *i;
        cv::LUT(channel.clone(), table, channel);
    }

    cv::Mat reduced;
    cv::merge(c, reduced);
    return reduced;
}
```

Comment: from where i can get the complete understanding and use of LUT ? i saw opencv documentation but its just strict to syntax. What you do if you want to save the values of this `LUT image` and want to apply it on other the same values

Comment: The purpose of LUT is to change an image's colors according to a lookup table. This can have various purposes, such as reducing color resolution as a preprocessing step in image segmentation. See this Wikipedia article for some extra information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_look-up_table

Comment: As for applying the same LUT transform to different images, you could modify the `colorReduce()` function above to accept a reference to a lookup table as argument, then calculate the table in a separate call to `lookupTable()` or any other method you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Both `i` and `n` are integers, therefore `i/n` is an integer. Perhaps you want it converted to double (`(double)i/n`) before taking the floor and multiplying by `n`?

Comment: how does your answer explain all that blue?

Comment: how many bytes is that uchar? you assume at least 3 bytes; even if it's wide char, it should still be 2 bytes, not 3 or more.